# バックグラウンド再生を検出する方法ありますか？

Tags: android, ios, unity3d, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x/unity3dのandroid/iosプラットフォーム開発で、他のアプリケーションがバックグラウンド再生で音楽等を再生しているか判断する方法はありますでしょうか？情報が無いのでandroid/iosそれぞれのnative処理でも構いません。

android・・・

Answer (score 4):

native 処理で構わないのであれば iOS では iOS6 以降からまさしくそのための API [otherAudioPlaying](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/otherAudioPlaying) が存在します。
iOS7 未満であれば `AudioSessionGetProperty` に `kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying` を指定することで取得することができます。実際に cocos2d-x でも[使用されています](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/1e11f3b3daeb187cde5dd8dc551eb9009ac7c621/cocos/audio/ios/CDAudioManager.m#L332-L337)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます！
そんな便利な関数があったなんて・・・。助かりました。